# PySpark: Create a column from ordered concatenation of columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am having an issue creating a new column from the **ordered** concatenation of two existing columns on a pyspark dataframe i.e.:

```
+------+------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | NewCol |
+------+------+--------+
| ORD  | DFW  | DFWORD |
| CUN  | MCI  | CUNMCI |
| LAX  | JFK  | JFKLAX |
+------+------+--------+
```

In other words, I want to grab Col1 and Col2, ordered them alphabetically and concatenate them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine `concat_ws`, `array` and `sort_array`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, array, sort_array

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("ORD", "DFW"), ("CUN", "MCI"), ("LAX", "JFK")],
    ("Col1", "Col2"))

df.withColumn("NewCol", concat_ws("", sort_array(array("Col1", "Col2")))).show()
# +----+----+------+        
# |Col1|Col2|NewCol|
# +----+----+------+
# | ORD| DFW|DFWORD|
# | CUN| MCI|CUNMCI|
# | LAX| JFK|JFKLAX|
# +----+----+------+
```